# Read stored file line by line in postgresql carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, carrierwave

I am using [carrierwave-postgresql](https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql) to store user uploaded files.

I have an uploader called FileUploader (in /app/uploaders/file_uploader.rb) with `storage :postgresql_lo`.

The uploaded files are linked to a column `:file_oid` in a model called UploadedFile (in app/models/uploaded_file.rb) with `mount_uploader :file_oid, FileUploader`:

```
class UploadedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file_oid, :processed, :type
  mount_uploader :file_oid, FileUploader
end
```

I upload a file as

```
f = UploadedFile.new
f.file_oid = params[:flat_file]
f.save!
```

Now when I try to read a file, the `read` method works fine, but I can't get an 'each' or 'open'.

```
> uf = UploadedFile.find(:first)
> uf.file_oid.read # works, gives the contents of the file
> uf.file_oid.file.read # this works too
> uf.file_oid.file.each
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::PostgresqlLo::File:0x000000039157a0>
> uf.file_oid.file.open
NoMethodError: private method `open' called for #<CarrierWave::Storage::PostgresqlLo::File:0x000000039157a0>
> uf.file_oid.open
NoMethodError: private method `open' called for /uploadedfile_file_oid/231132:FileUploader
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CarrierWave::Storage::PostgresqlLo::File`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave-postgresql/CarrierWave/Storage/PostgresqlLo/File) class doesn't support anything fancy like `each` or `open`; you can't do much with one of those objects beyond reading the whole thing, writing the whole thing, or getting the size.

However, if you look at the `read` implementation, you'll see this:

```
@uploader.model.transaction do
  lo = connection.lo_open(identifier)
  content = connection.lo_read(lo, file_length)
  connection.lo_close(lo)
  content
end
```

so you could bypass carrierwave-postgresql entirely and read the [large object](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/largeobjects.html) chunk by chunk using the underlying [`lo_open`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#lo_open-instance_method), [`lo_read`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#lo_read-instance_method), and [`lo_close`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#lo_close-instance_method) methods on the `connection`. You won't be able to read the large object line by line of course as the large object system doesn't know what a *line* is, it just knows about a seekable byte stream.